# Installing an iOS app from Xcode over the same app downloaded from the app store (or vice versa)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, provisioning-profile, app-id

What are the details or rules governing what will work here? Does it have to do with certificates/provisioning profile or just the bundle id?

If for example I have a user who has an issue with app downloaded from the App Store and I want to examine their app bundle, can I attach their iOS device to a Mac with XCode, compile the app overtop the app store version, and then download the bundle from the Device Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want, but both the AppStore and replacement app must have the same bundle ID and be signed with certificates from the same developer account.